# How can I access a JCR Version of a deleted node?

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I'd like to access the javax.jcr.version.VersionHistory of a node that has been deleted to read metadata and change labels, or possibly restore it.  How can I do that? The JCR [VersionManager](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/version/VersionManager.html) provides methods `getBaseVersion(java.lang.String absPath)` and `getVersionHistory(java.lang.String absPath)` that throw a `PathNotFoundException` when the node at absPath has been deleted, although the data is still around in the /jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage .

I'm using jackrabbit-oak 1.6.1, in case that's relevant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the versioned node is deleted, revision data is still there in `/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage`, if you have enough info about the node, you can search for its versions, `nt:frozenNode` nodes -

```
--jcr sql2
SELECT * FROM [nt:frozenNode] as n WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE ([/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage]) and n.[jcr:title] LIKE "name%"
```

version node can be cast to `javax.jcr.version.Version`;

`Version version = (Version) frozenNode.getParent();`

and restored using `VersionManager.restore()` -

```
VersionManager versionManager = session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager();
versionManager.restore(path, version, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, if the version-controlled node is deleted, access to its version history based on the original path isn't possible anymore.

This means that you'll have to keep track of that information before the node is deleted.

Comment: So I can't even restore it, once it's deleted? If that's possible, and if I want to change labels on versions, I need to restore it, change labels, and delete it again? 8-}

Comment: I *think* that is true (see https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/15_Versioning.html#15.7%20Restoring%20a%20Version for more information)

Comment: I think, the trick is to locate the corresponding `nt:versionHistory` or `nt:frozenNode` node in `/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage`, from there you should be able to restore. it is possible in AEM, which uses oak with some custom impl, cant say for sure about vanilla jackrabbit oak.

Comment: Yes, you need to locate the version history node. That's hard once the version-controlled node was deleted. If you have it, you can retrieve version information, but AFAIU, you can't use the `restore` method, as it requires a version-controlled node.

Comment: @awd It's easy to locate the versionHistory, but with what method do you perform that restore, even at AEM?

Comment: `nt:versionHistory` and `nt:frozenNode` can be cast to `VersionHistory` and Version respectively, which implement restore methods, see unit tests for reference [here](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit/blob/b23d6734381e49f236c3705820126803555608b5/jackrabbit-jcr-tests/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/test/api/version/VersionTest.java#L724) and [here](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit/blob/b23d6734381e49f236c3705820126803555608b5/jackrabbit-jcr-tests/src/main/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/test/api/version/VersionHistoryTest.java#L992)

Comment: @awd Ah! That's a good tip - I never thought that just (Version) frozenNode would work. Then VersionManager.restore(String, Version, boolean) does it's thing. Do you want to put that into an answer? Otherwise I'll create one myself.